# Integrating Cucumber BDD tests with SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, bdd, cucumber-java

My Cucumber BDD tests run a little differently. I am running them in a unix server since the application runs there through a cronjob and using run(options). The json and html reports generated are stored in the unix servers. I need to be able to get code coverage for these BDD tests.

Any suggestions on how i could get this? On some research I came across:

https://github.com/racodond/sonar-gherkin-plugin.

However, I am not sure how to get this integrated with my tests. The readme was not very clear to me. We already have sonarQube integration for our unit tests. Would be great to get BDD test coverage uploaded there as well. Code is in java and they are using maven.

Other solutions not involving sonarqube are also welcome :)

Comment: Could merging the two generated code coverage files be an option?

Comment: There is no code coverage file generated for cucumber. How do i get that to happen?

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: I am using eclipse as the IDE but tests are run in the server